Spring webclient handling of http response with trailer
I'm using the spring webclient to make my api calls, and one of the calls has a optional trailer response if anything went wrong. The response is chunked encoded.
A simple example:
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/binary
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout-20
< Date: Fri, 03 May 2024 14:26:43 GMT
< Cache-Control: max-age=1
< accept-ranges: bytes
<
0
x-result: 1
x-error: Failed to determine asset size

If i make the request the response body is empty for the above, but i can't access the trailer headers.
List<byte[]> response = webClient.get().uri( "https://apiwithtailerresponse.com" )
                .retrieve().bodyToFlux( byte[].class )
                .collectList()
                .block();

Any way to retrieve the trailer headers values?

have you tried  toEntityFlux?

yes i have, the response entity has nothing about the trailers. A printout of the headers of the entity:
[Transfer-Encoding:"chunked", Content-Type:"text/binary", Connection:"Keep-Alive", Keep-Alive:"timeout-20", Date:"Fri, 03 May 2024 14:26:43 GMT", Cache-Control:"max-age=1", x-ee-cameraid:"100f9718", accept-ranges:"bytes", x-ee-archiverid:"a1545.eencloud.com", trailer:"x-een-result,x-een-error"]

Also tried adding a custom BodyExtractor, but the trailer data is not part of the ReactiveHttpInputMessage.getBody()

It looks like underlining netty client has trailing headers support https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1837. You can probably check how it’s used in webclient

I filed a feature request with spring, but it seems non of their http clients has so far been able to handle trailer data

Thanks you for raising this enhancement request in Spring Framework, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/32890.
For consistency, we would need to implement this in WebClient, RestTemplate and RestClient - and pay extra attention to adding this feature in the right place in our existing fluent APIs.
On the server side, the Servlet 4.0 spec supports trailer fields and so does Reactor Netty, but we would need to ensure that all other supported servers do so.
